# MemoryError: memory allocation failed in Micropython with Raspberry pi Pico

Tags: json, memory, ram, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

The code saves the data from some sensors together with the date and time that the sensor is taken, what it does is tell me what was the minimum and maximum in the course of 24 hours, only that there comes a point where the memory error appears , how can I solve it? Thank you

```
import time, machine, math, binascii, os, json, micropython, gc
from machine import I2C, UART, Pin
from mpl3115a2 import MPL3115A2
from SI7021 import SI7021
from picozero import Button
from micropyGPS import MicropyGPS

#I2C Start
i2c = I2C(1)
si7021 = SI7021(i2c)
i2cmpl = machine.I2C(1, scl = machine.Pin(7), sda = machine.Pin(6))
mpl = MPL3115A2(i2cmpl, mode=MPL3115A2.ALTITUDE)
mpl2 = MPL3115A2(i2cmpl, mode=MPL3115A2.PRESSURE)

#Inicio GPS
gps = machine.UART(1, 9600)
my_gps = MicropyGPS(-7)

# Nombre del archivo de texto donde se guardarán los valores del sensor
filename = "datos.json"



#Borrado de contenido
def eraser():
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        pass
    
# Función para obtener la hora actual
def get_current_time():
    current_time = utime.localtime()
    return "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d} {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(current_time[0], current_time[1], current_time[2], current_time[3], current_time[4], current_time[5])
    
def leer_maxmin():
    
    gc.collect()
    
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        json_content = file.read()
        
    # Convertir el contenido del archivo en una lista de objetos Python
    data_list = json_content.strip().split('\n')
    data_objects = [json.loads(line) for line in data_list]

    #Historicos Temperatura
    max_temperature = max([obj['Temperatura'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_temperature = min([obj['Temperatura'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Temperatura'] == max_temperature:
            max_timeTe = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Temperatura'] == min_temperature:
            min_timeTe = obj['|']
            pass
            
    print('(Temperatura)', '||', max_timeTe, 'Maximo:', max_temperature, '||',min_timeTe, 'Minimo:', min_temperature)
    
    #Historicos Humedad
    max_humidity = max([obj['Humedad'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_humidity = min([obj['Humedad'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Humedad'] == max_humidity:
            max_timeHu = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Humedad'] == min_humidity:
            min_timeHu = obj['|']
            pass
    print('(Humedad)','||', max_timeHu, 'Maximo:', max_humidity, '||', min_timeHu, 'Minimo:', min_humidity)
    
    
    #Historicos Altitud
    max_alture = max([obj['Altura'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_alture = min([obj['Altura'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Altura'] == max_alture:
            max_timeAl = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Altura'] == min_alture:
            min_timeAl = obj['|']
            pass
    print('(Altura)', '||', max_timeAl, 'Maximo:', max_alture , '||', min_timeAl, 'Minimo:', min_alture)
    
    #Historicos Presion
    max_presion = max([obj['Presion'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_presion = min([obj['Presion'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Presion'] == max_presion:
            max_timePr = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Presion'] == min_presion:
            min_timePr = obj['|']
            pass
    print('(Presion)', '||', max_timePr, 'Maximo:', max_presion, '||', min_timePr, 'Minimo:', min_presion)
    
    #Historicos Lux
    max_lux = max([obj['Lux'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_lux = min([obj['Lux'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Lux'] == max_lux:
            max_timeLx = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Lux'] == min_lux:
            min_timeLx = obj['|']
            pass
    print('(Lux)', '||', max_timeLx, 'Maximo:', max_lux, '||', min_timeLx, 'Minimo:', min_lux)
    
    max_Rain = max([obj['Lluvia'] for obj in data_objects])
    min_Rain = min([obj['Lluvia'] for obj in data_objects])
    for obj in data_objects:
        if obj['Lluvia'] == max_Rain:
            max_timeRG = obj['|']
            pass
        if obj['Lluvia'] == min_Rain:
            min_timeRG = obj['|']
            pass
    print('(Lluvia)', '||', max_timeRG, 'Maximo:', max_Rain, '||', min_timeRG, 'Minimo:', min_Rain)
    
    
    
#eraser()
    
while True:
    
    gc.collect()
    
    #Offset UTC-7
    my_gps.local_offset
    
    #Formato Fecha y hora
    horas, minutos, segundos = map(int, my_gps.timestamp)
    segundos = round(segundos)
    dia, mes, anio = map(int, my_gps.date)
    
    my_gps.satellite_data_updated()
    
    #Lectura de datos GPS
    sentence = gps.readline()
    if sentence:
        for x in sentence:
            my_gps.update(chr(x))
    
    timeUTC = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(horas, minutos, segundos)
    dateNew = '{:02d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(dia, mes, anio)
    
    # Obtener la hora actual
    timestamp = dateNew + " " + timeUTC
    
    #Luz ADC
    sensor_luz = machine.ADC(26)
    eficacia_luz = 90
    reading = sensor_luz.read_u16()
    corriente = (reading / 10000)
    
    #Rain Drop sensor Start
    raindrop = machine.ADC(28)
    rain_status = ''
    rain_drop = raindrop.read_u16()
    if rain_drop >= 51000:
        rainIf = 'False'
        count = 0.0
            
    elif rain_drop <= 50000:
        rainIf = 'True'
    
    #Valor Sensores
    sensor_lum = (round(corriente * eficacia_luz, 2))
    sensor_temp = (round(si7021.temperature(), 2))
    sensor_hum = (round(si7021.humidity(), 2))
    sensor_alt = (round(mpl.altitude()/1000, 2))
    sensor_pres = mpl2.pressure()

    # Crear un diccionario con los datos del sensor y la hora actual
    data = {"|": timestamp, "Temperatura": sensor_temp, "Humedad": sensor_hum, "Altura": sensor_alt, "Presion": sensor_pres, "Lux": sensor_lum, "Lluvia": rainIf}
    
    
    # Abrir el archivo en modo escritura y agregar los datos al final del archivo
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        # Serializar el diccionario a formato JSON y escribirlo en el archivo
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
        f.write("\n")
    
    print(str(gc.mem_free()))
    print(str(gc.mem_alloc()))
    micropython.alloc_emergency_exception_buf(100)
    
    gc.collect()

    leer_maxmin()
        
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

It is saved as follows in a json file:

`{"|": "17-04-23 12:34:47", "Altura": 25.23, "Lux": 26.21, "Humedad": 30.62, "Presion": 100929.7, "Lluvia": "False", "Temperatura": 24.06}`

iterating and writing on the line below the following sample

`{"|": "17-04-23 12:34:47", "Altura": 25.23, "Lux": 26.21, "Humedad": 30.62, "Presion": 100929.7, "Lluvia": "False", "Temperatura": 24.06} {"|": "17-04-23 12:34:47", "Altura": 25.24, "Lux": 27.65, "Humedad": 30.62, "Presion": 100940.0, "Lluvia": "False", "Temperatura": 24.08} {"|": "17-04-23 12:34:47", "Altura": 25.24, "Lux": 25.34, "Humedad": 30.64, "Presion": 100944.3, "Lluvia": "False", "Temperatura": 24.05}`

This is the error it throws after 100 samples:

```
stack: 484 out of 7936
GC: total: 192064, used: 56528, free: 135536
 No. of 1-blocks: 534, 2-blocks: 164, max blk sz: 242, max free sz: 1174
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 189, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 42, in leer_maxmin
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 11440 bytes
```